# Cross-compiling mDNSPosix to armv6, "unable to recognise format of mdnsd"

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, armv6, mdns

I'm trying to compile mDNS for ARMv6 to use in embedded applications on Axis cameras. I do this on Ubuntu 4.8.0-27. I'm not an expert on makefiles, but I tried to replace mDNSPosix' makefile gcc commands with Axis bundled arm-axis-linux-gnueabi-gcc, and run the makefile to compile this: https://opensource.apple.com/source/mDNSResponder/mDNSResponder-625.41.2/mDNSPosix/

It went okey until a certain line in the makefile that gave me this error:

```
strip: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `build/prod/mdnsd'
Makefile:251: recipe for target 'build/prod/mdnsd' failed
make: *** [build/prod/mdnsd] Error 1
```

The modified makefile: http://pastebin.com/wbhGC5s1

Any hints how to proceed with this error and change the makefile to work?

Thanks

Comment: Does your cross-toolchain not provide a suitable version of strip? No need to get hung up on makefiles, the error means exactly what it says: your host version of strip doesn't understand the executable format it's being given.

Comment: Not completely sure it has. Should I just try to cross-compile strip for arm too? "lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Oct 22 16:22 /usr/bin/strip -> x86_64-linux-gnu-strip"